# Converting date from database to a different timezone

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I have a website that allows people to post things. When they post, it gets inserted into the database and the database adds a timestamp.

When I hosted the database on my local machine, the timestamps were in my time zone.  My new hosting website has it set to GMT time.

How can I make it display the time in my time zone? I've tried adding

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

to my views just under the  tag, but that doesn't help.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you change the timezone on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Set the time zone
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

// Create the datetime and set the timestamp
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimestamp($timestamp);

// Convert it
$dateTime->setTimeZone($dateTimeZone);

echo $dateTime->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```

Should work I guess

Comment: Do this when I insert to the database, instead of using the databases timestamp functionality?

Comment: Well there are two ways to go. Either create the datetime value/timestamp value on your web server and insert that on your database (thus storing the time at your web server's time zone) or get the time in GMT and convert it on your website. (The example on my answer) It would be best to sync the two however. This will get you in trouble for sure at some point (forgetting a NOW() somewhere)

Comment: your example gives me this error

    Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimeZone() on a non-object

Comment: Have you set the default timezone with date_default_timezone_set()? This is for PHP 5.3. On which version are you on? I just tested it again and it works