# Changing timezone of a retrieved date in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, drupal

I am retrieving a date in format of 2013-09-15 08:45:00 from the database, which is set in UTC and I need to change it to another dynamic timezone (based on user)

So far I've got

```
$datetime = $row->field_data_field_performance_times_field_performance_times_v;
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime, new DateTimeZone($user->timezone));
$performance_time = date_format($eventDate, 'l, j F, Y, H:i');
```

But it doesn't change the timezone. Any ideas what's wrong? It should be +2 hours in my case.

Comment: There's an answer here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114195/converting-date-from-database-to-a-different-timezone

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that :( It seemed to behave the same way as with my code above.

Comment: hmm..you have tagged this as drupal. have you tried the drupal format_date function?

Comment: No, I haven't. Will do, thanks.

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your input datetime is in UTC, not user's timezone. So first you must create datetime object in UTC, and then set/change timezone to user's :

```php
$dt = new DateTime('2013-09-15 08:45:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
print_r($dt);
/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-09-15 08:45:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
*/
```

Now you have datetime in UTC timezone. If you wish to change timezone, just call `->setTimezone()` on DateTime object :

```php
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
print_r($dt);
/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-09-15 10:45:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
*/
```

p.s. because input `2013-09-15 08:45:00` is in standard datetime format, you don't need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat`.