# Change database timestamp output based on user timezone

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, timezone, timestamp

This has never been necessary before when I've been using timestamps before, but for some reason all of my timestamps are 7 hours behind. Now I could change the database timezone and be done with it, but what about my visitors from other countries?

So what I'm asking is, is there any way I can possibly do this on PHPMyAdmin, or in SQL? Or do I have to use PHP? In which case where do I even start?

Comment: You should write a script in `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to keep the way you're storing dates in your database consistent, and localize for specific users, as in this example:

[Changing timezone of a retrieved date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810359/changing-timezone-of-a-retrieved-date-in-php)

Comment: Looks great, I run every date through an script as well so it'll be easy to change. I am however using "timestamp"s, does it matter? - And also, the script doesn't automatically discover what timezone they need does it?

Comment: Just convert the format if you need to.  Yes, as in the example linked, you can check what timezone someone is in to switch to.

Comment: I tried creating a code but could not figure it out. If I have the timestamp from the DB saved in $timestamp, would you create a sample code?